# Failed to mount /sysroot

Tags: linux, kernel, grub, initramfs

i get the follow error when try bootar a custom kernel:

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount /sysroot
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for initrd root file system.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Mounts configured in the Real Root.

You are in emergency mode. Afeter logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exite" to bot into default mode.
```

i only compile the kernel 6.5-rc2:
`sudo make -j16`

then i install modules:
`sudo make modules_install`

then building bzImage on boot/x86, i move for /boot: 
`cp -v arch/x86/boot/bzImage /boot/vmlinuz-linux6.5.2`

i make the new mkinitcpio:

```
# mkinitcpio preset file for the 'linux' package

#ALL_config="/etc/mkinitcpio.conf"
ALL_kver="/boot/vmlinuz-linux6.5.2"
ALL_microcode=(/boot/*-ucode.img)

PRESETS=('default' 'fallback')

#default_config="/etc/mkinitcpio.conf"
default_image="/boot/initramfs-linux6_5_2.img"
#default_uki="/efi/EFI/Linux/arch-linux.efi"
#default_options="--splash /usr/share/systemd/bootctl/splash-arch.bmp"

#fallback_config="/etc/mkinitcpio.conf"
fallback_image="/boot/initramfs-linux6_5_2-fallback.img"
#fallback_uki="/efi/EFI/Linux/arch-linux-fallback.efi"
fallback_options="-S autodetect"
```

i create the initramfs:
`sudo mkinitcpio -p linux6_5_2`

and finnaly i update the grub: `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

although, when i try boot the kernel6.5-rc2 i get the error above mentionated

This is my lsblk:

```
sda      8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
- sda1   8:1    0  93,1G  0 part /boot
- sda2   8:2    0 144,4G  0 part /
zram0  254:0    0   3,8G  0 disk [SWAP]
```

this is my arch.conf:

```
## This is just an example config file.
## Please edit the paths and kernel parameters according to your system.

title   Arch Linux
linux   /vmlinuz-linux
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
options root=/dev/sda2 PARTUUID=XXXX rootfstype=ext4 add_efi_memmap
```

i think important mentionated that i seeing my journalctl and dont have any information for the kernel6.5-rc2

So, i try recompile the kernel with another `.config` .... i take a config from kernel 6.5-rc1 (that i also compile and it work in my machine) but the 6.5-rc2 dont work.